# HTML tags in RichTextInput gets converted to string

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin 2.9.8 with ra-input-rich-text 2.9.3.

When I want to insert an  tag to the RichTextInput field, it gets converted to strings.

I want to add somthing like this:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

and it will appear like:

```
<p><span style="color: mediumblue;">&lt;</span><span style="color: rgb(165, 42, 42);">img</span><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;src</span><span style="color: mediumblue;">="smiley.gif"</span><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;alt</span><span style="color: mediumblue;">="Smiley face"</span><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;height</span><span style="color: mediumblue;">="42"</span><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;width</span><span style="color: mediumblue;">="42"&gt;</span></p>
```

How can I insert a simple  HTML Tag? I don't want to insert the full picture, I just want a link onto my page.

Answer (score 0):

React discourages setting html from code, or using innerHTML because of the risk involved. For this reason, reacts requires that you understand the risks and proceed at your own peril. To get html tags to work, you must do this

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html: yourHTML
}}></div>`

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where should I add this code snippet to?